# SQL SERVER 2005 CASE WHEN THEN END

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I am running following query..

```
Select T1.* from T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.C3 = T3.C3
ORDER BY Case When T1.C1 = 'ABC' THEN 'XYZ' END  AS COMMENTS
```

Its giving me Syntax error near AS. Unable to figure out the error.

Comment: Motive -> I want to save the comparison result in a column name Comments. Should i use IF statement with ORDER BY for this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you are trying to assign an alias to the ORDER BY clause - this is not allowed and I'm not sure what you want to achieve here?

You either need:

```
Select T1.* from T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.C3 = T3.C3
ORDER BY Case When T1.C1 = 'ABC' THEN 'XYZ' END
```

Or, if you want that CASE value to be returned in the SELECT as well, then you need:

```
Select T1.*, Case When T1.C1 = 'ABC' THEN 'XYZ' END AS COMMENTS
from T1 
    LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 
    LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.C3 = T3.C3
ORDER BY Case When T1.C1 = 'ABC' THEN 'XYZ' END
```

Also, again not sure of intention here so it depends, but you may need an ELSE on that CASE...
e.g.

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN T1.C1 = 'ABC' THEN 'XYZ' ELSE T1.C1 END
```

Comment: What if i want to save the comparison result in another column name Comments.. will IF statement be useful??

Comment: @rahulshukla - Can you elaborate, I don't quite follow? My 2nd example above returns the result of the comparison in an extra "COMMENTS" column - is that what you mean?

Answer (score 4):

You don't need the `AS` alias when using case in an order by

```
Select T1.* from T1 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.C1 = T2.C1 
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.C3 = T3.C3
ORDER BY Case When T1.C1 = 'ABC' THEN 'XYZ' END
```

Comment: I'm not aware of `AS` being needed at all, in an `ORDER BY`.

Comment: What if i want to save the comparison result in another column name Comments.. will IF statement be useful??